# List of default iOS control heights and widths for each device?

Tags: ios, storyboard

For example: in the storyboard, a label defaults to a height of 44. A lone navigation bar defaults to a width of 375 and a height of 44. The height, however, actually renders on the device at 64. Are these values the same regardless of device? Is the nav bar still 64, even on an iPad Pro, for example? Is there a specific aspect ratio for any given control that determines height/width on all devices?

This kind of information would be very helpful when, say, manually setting constraints on something, such as the Launch Screen storyboard.

**My actual question is**: where might I find a helpful reference to the *default* height/width or aspect ratio values of available controls for iOS devices.

Comment: navigation bar is always 44. the sum of 64 is navigation bar (44) + status bar (20). and yes it will be the same even for ipad pro

Comment: Yep, @TungFam. Looking for that kind of info on *all* the UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS only a few things of have Intrinsic Size.

UILabel is determined by the text string,font, and font size and weight.

UIImageView has an intrinsic content size to the size of the image.

Controls may contain text or images that give them a size. The intrinsic size is determined my the text and images. Example the size of UIButton which is determined my the image , background image or the text or UIsegmentedControl which I think is determined my the number of segments and the text size.

UIStatusbar, UINavigationBar, UITabbar etc are fixed by the system.  But I would not want to depend on fixed values that could change. Here is a link to some common system defined element sizes. http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

You can also find this in the Apple Design Guidelines.

The bars have a fixed system size. With everything else it is determined by the content. Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that if I change the font, add images, etc, of course the height and width will change. However, if I drag items to the storyboard, and make no changes to them, there is a default size. And, system-set items still have a default size as demonstrated by the nav bar (44) and status bar (20). I'm sure I could determine these things via experimentation. I was just hoping for a reference, maybe by someone who had already done the experimentation ;-)

Comment: So you want to know the default size of a uilabel that has the text "label" with the standard font size?

Comment: Sure! Drag a label onto the storyboard, and check the Size Inspector: width = 42, height = 21. The width, of course, is based on that "Label" text content. I'd be more concerned with the default height of 21. Assuming I don't need to change the System font, size 17, I can use that height in calculating my screen arrangement. If it doesn't change on a bigger device, that helps me determine how I need to set my constraints, perhaps.

Comment: Why would you do that. Why would you not check on load or just Autolayout? Suppose apple changes the default font size on a next version and all your calculations would be wrong. What if you want font to size to fit if it is super long?  My point is you cannot rely on such measurement to lay your ui out. You could get your ui elements on layout subviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews but don't depend on a premeasured size to lay it out. You would also have to measure all your ui with proper text before hand. Sounds very inefficient.

Comment: Launch Screen storyboard

Comment: You cannot write code for the launch screen storyboard so I don't know what the benefit would be.  You would need to use springs and struts or AutoLayout to position and size your views.

Answer (score 0):

> where might I find a helpful reference to the default height/width or aspect ratio values of available controls for iOS devices.

A most helpful reference for what iOS user interfaces should look like is [*iOS Human Interface Guidelines*](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/). Although it doesn't have the list of default dimensions that you're looking for, it *does* have a [*Resources*](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/resources/) section that includes packages of "smart objects" for Photoshop or Sketch that you can use to quickly mock up UI designs using standard-sized controls without having to worry too much about specific sizes.